# Validate LinkedIn oAuth2 access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, linkedin-api

I have recently worked on **Google oAuth2** and was able to authorize and validate the token.

I do not see any such option for LinkedIn. Unlike Google, LinkedIn asks users to perform a HTTP request to know if the token is valid or not and then the user cannot even validate the access_token as it is its own format and not like JWT.

Any idea what are the best practices or right approach to validate a LinkedIn access_token and is there a way to  convert that token to JWT ?

Thank you !